# Invalid Syntax Error in Python package RSeQC

Tags: python

I am trying to run a function called read_distribution.py in a Python package called RSeQC. However when I run the following command:

```
 python3 read_distribution.py -i mysample.bam -r hg38_RefSeq.bed
```

I get the following error:

```
 File "distribution.py", line 278
     print  "%-30s%d" % ("Total Reads",totalReads)
                   ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Lines 275-282 in the read_distribution.py code look like this:

```
 except StopIteration:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Finished\n"                

print "%-30s%d" % ("Total Reads",totalReads)
print  "%-30s%d" % ("Total Tags",totalFrags)
print  "%-30s%d" % ("Total Assigned Tags",totalFrags-unAssignFrags)

print  "====================================================================="
```

Is this a problem with my python version? I do not know enough Python to figure out the problem so any help is appreciated-Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this package? I did some searching and found an old package on sourceforge version 2.6.4 dated around 2016 and a new package on pypi version 4.0.0 for python 3.  You could try `python3 -m pip uninstall RSeQC` to get rid of the old, and then `python3 -m pip install RSeQC` to get the new.

Comment: @tdelaney ahhh ok I will try this. I think I was looking at the Sourceforge code

Comment: I should have mentioned that's pypi.python.org (now just pypi.org) the official python repository and the default place `pip` looks for packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're using Python 3.X.  Starting with 3.0, the `print` statement became a function, requiring parentheses to be used like when calling any function.  So the code you show needs to look like this to work in Python 3.X:

```
print("%-30s%d" % ("Total Reads",33))
print("%-30s%d" % ("Total Tags",33))
print("%-30s%d" % ("Total Assigned Tags",12))

print("=====================================================================")
```

There are scripts on the internet that will convert much of your Python 2.X code to 3.X if you have a bunch more of it to convert.  Alternately, if you got the code from somewhere else, maybe they have a Python 3.X version available.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this package was written in Python 2, which didn't have you putting ()'s after print, in Python 3 this changed to have you put ()'s after print, You're using Python 3.